# setState is not updating value

Tags: dart, flutter

**Problem:**
setState is not saving the value of *_products.*

**Tried:**
If I print the value of *_products* inside the setState function, it is updated:

```
['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'New Product']
```

But when I pass *_products* to my *Products* class, the value of *_products* is reset:

```
['Product 1', 'Product 2']
```

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './products.dart';

class ProductManager extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ProductManagerState();
  }
}

class _ProductManagerState extends State<ProductManager> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<String> _products = ['Product 1', 'Product 2'];
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _products.add('New Product');
              });
            },
            child: Text('Add Product'),
          ),
        ),
        Products(_products),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Initialize the `_products` list outside the `build` function.

Every time you call `setState()`, the `build()` method is called which resets `_products` since it's initialized inside the method.

Try doing this:

```
class _ProductManagerState extends State<ProductManager> {

  List<String> _products = ['Product 1', 'Product 2'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   /*Rest of the code*/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One golden rule to keep in mind while writing Flutter apps:

> Widgets are immutable.

That meaning, anything declare inside a Widget (**Stateful or Stateless**) will not change after being build the very first time.

The state object (i.e. *_ProductManagerState*) while mutable, will not reflect any changes in the Widget (Golden Rule One).

Updates will only be reflected, if and if only if the widget is being rebuilt (**note: rebuilding of widget =/= rebuilding of class!**). Thus, when calling *setState*, it does not only add the product to the list but also forced a rebuild. This is why *setState* is needed at the first place.

Hence as others suggested, moving the initialization of _products out of the build will solve the problem of it not "saving".

It does save, just that it got re-initialize every time the widget re-build itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './products.dart';

class ProductManager extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ProductManagerState();
  }
}

class _ProductManagerState extends State<ProductManager> {

  List<String> _products = ['Product 1', 'Product 2'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _products.add('New Product');
              });
            },
            child: Text('Add Product'),
          ),
        ),
        Products(_products),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```